# Как убрать стандартную смену слайдов на слайдере Swiper?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Как убрать стандартную смену слайдов на слайдере Swiper  ?
И поставить обычную плавную замену картинок без никаких выезжаний з правого края ?
То есть нужно чтобы следующий слайд просто заменял предыдущий и все без никакой анимации.
У меня стоит смена слайдов по времени если что.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вам подойдет опция [effect: 'fade'](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-effect) из [API Swiperjs](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api), чтобы использовать анимацию плавного появления и исчезновения слайдов в качестве анимации смены активного слайда.

При использовании данной опции, вы должны иметь ввиду, что этот режим предполагает один активный слайд.

Пример для наглядности:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper Fade эффект</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      effect: "fade",
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

В дополнение можете управлять продолжительностью смены слайдов через опцию [speed: 0](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-speed), чтобы сделать мгновенную смену слайда:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper Fade эффект</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/css/swiper.min.css">

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      position: relative;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    body {
      background: #eee;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #000;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .swiper {
      width: 100%;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide {
      background-position: center;
      background-size: cover;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .swiper-slide img {
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.3.3/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      effect: "fade",
      speed: 0,
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

У Swiper отличная [документация](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api), есть даже примеры с кодом как и что сделать, всё что вам нужно, чуть-чуть почитать и проявить смекалку.

Демо замены слайда - https://swiperjs.com/demos#effect-fade
Опция автоплея - https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#autoplay
Скорость анимации - https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-speed

Сможете самостоятельно объединить?